# Bootstrap Typeahead render issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I am using bootstrap 3 with typeahead and I am having an issue getting it to format correctly.

My Jquery :

```
$('input.query').typeahead({
    name: 'query',
    value: 'ntid',
    remote : 'jsonUser.php?query=%QUERY',
    minLength: 3,
    template: '<p><strong>{{ntid}}</strong> – {{name}}</p>',
    engine: Hogan,
    limit: 10  
});
```

When I enter 3 characters this is the JSON response.

```
[
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "qid": "Q1234",
    "empID": "123",
    "ntid": "test"
},
{
    "name": "Bob Jones",
    "qid": "Q5678",
    "empID": "456",
    "ntid": "testing"
},
{
    "name": "Mike James",
    "qid": "Q2233",
    "empID": "789",
    "ntid": "tester"
},
{
    "name": "Harry Potter",
    "qid": "Q2212",
    "empID": "223",
    "ntid": "testit"
}
]
```

However, this is the result on the dropdown.

[image]

As you can see it only shows 1 result even though there are 4 in the response.

As a side note, when I click on that only response, the drop down list just disappears, doesn't get entered into the text field.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to add :

```
    valueKey: 'ntid' as an option.
```

Complete:

```
    $('input.query').typeahead({
    name: 'query',
    value: 'ntid',
    remote : 'jsonUser.php?query=%QUERY',
    minLength: 3,
    template: '<p><strong>{{ntid}}</strong> – {{name}}</p>',
    engine: Hogan,
    limit: 10  ,
    valueKey: 'ntid'
});
```

The valueKey setting is the json tag that I am searching in.